# Google Play Games API and Scope

Tags: api, service, scope, google-play-games

I have been trying to find a good answer to my question for a long time.
My issue is kinda simple.

When accessing Google Play Games API, Google advise us not to ask for unnecessary scopes.

In [this post,](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) the example of a good way to acces the API without having a consent screen is this way:

```
 // This way you won’t get a consent screen  
 GoogleApiClient gac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)  
           .addApi(Games.API)  
           .build();  
 // This way you won’t get a consent screen
```

In the [Play Game Services Guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init), they give this example

```
// Create the Google Api Client with access to the Play Games services
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
        .build();
```

So my question is about the "addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)". When adding it, the user gets a consent screen for age range, gamer profile and something like that I don't really remember.

What is it for? What is the difference between the two? **What do I not have access to** if I just don't use it and just use addApi(Games.API) without adding the scope.

My game only needs to display the player usernames and playerids for Multiplayer. Do I need to addScope ? Because I don't really wanna have a consent window showing up when signing in, for nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the [Google Play Docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html#SCOPE_GAMES), serveral functions, including `getCurrentAccountName()` require the `SCOPE_GAMES`. So if you want to show your players username, you will need to add the scope. (Additionally, for the username the permission: `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` is required)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I get the username with getCurretPlayer().displayName(); and it works fine. So I guess I don&#39;t need that get_accounts permission but only the scope.